# Can I get my Schengen visa reissued in Germany?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, international-travel

I have lost my passport with my Schengen visa in Germany.  I have just acquired a new passport but no visa yet and I need to travel ASAP. I am a foreign exchange student in Germany. What can I do to travel?

Comment: Related questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/lost-passport-with-schengen-visa and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/travelling-without-a-visa-after-passport-was-stolen Unfortunately no definitive answer, it would be great if someone came back to share their experience.

Comment: You should probably contact the German authorities (perhaps the Ministry of Foreign Affairs) ASAP. Whatever people tell you here, you will most likely need to do it anyway at some point and they will be able to provide an authoritative answer. Your own consulate might also be able to assist (… or not)

Comment: If there's no definitive answer for your question, Please share whatever your steps later in this website so everybody else can learn.

Comment: If you are a foreign exchange student in Germany I assume you have some temporary resident permit there, and are already within Schengen. If so, you don't need a Schengen visa at all.